# Convert element list to integer and shift to right

Tags: python, serial-port, bit-shift, pyserial

I working on python code that read one byte at time from serial and store it into list.

Next I need to combine two bytes to obtain the payload length. To achieve this goal I need to convert the MSB (Most significative byte) and LSB (Least significative byte) of length to integer and then shift the MSB.

This is my List: ['H', '4', 'K', 'M', '0', '\x10', '\xff', '\x10', '\x00', '\x02', '\xff', '\xff'].

**MSB** is **'\x02'** ans **LSB** is **'\x00'**

I store MSB and LSB in two variables and I tried to convert it to int from string by int():

```
payloadLenMSB_h = int(packetHeader[offsetPayloadLenMSB])
payloadLenLSB_h = int(packetHeader[offsetPayloadLenLSB])
```

But I receive this error:

```
**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**
```

In which way I can convert the MSB and LSB of length to int?

Next I nedd to shift MSB to right by 8 bit and conbine it with LSB.

Any suggestions?

This is my code to read data from serial:

```
print 'Available data on COM Port: ' + str(availableSerialByte)
if availableSerialByte > 0:
    readByte = serialCOM.read(1)
    print 'Read COM byte:' + str(readByte)
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import struct
payloadLenMSB_h = struct.unpack('B', packetHeader[offsetPayloadLenMSB])[0]
payloadLenLSB_h = struct.unpack('B', packetHeader[offsetPayloadLenLSB])[0]
payloadLen = payloadLenMSB_h << 8 + payloadLenLSB_h
```

The `'B'` denotes a single unsigned char, see [the struct docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters). `<<` means bitwise shift, once your MSB has been shifted you can simply add it to the LSB.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It's works fine!

payloadLenMSB_h = ord(packetHeader[offsetPayloadLenMSB])
payloadLenLSB_h = ord(packetHeader[offsetPayloadLenLSB])

Is correct?